# Jupyter Notebook Widget slider not working if value is less than one (Interactive Matplotlib graph)

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, widget

I have a slider as such:

```
beta = widgets.IntSlider(description = 'beta', value=0.2, min=0, max=1.0, step = 0.1, readout_format='.2f')
```

However, it will not step correctly. It only goes from 0 to 1. Actually, when I introduce the "step = 0.1" into the line of code, it will not run at all (it stays stuck at 0 and I cannot move the slider). Does anyone know why this is happening??

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

The issue is that I had the slider as an integer, rather than a float.
The correct code is:

```
widgets.FloatSlider(
value=7.5,
min=0,
max=10.0,
step=0.1,
description='Test:',
disabled=False,
continuous_update=False,
orientation='horizontal',
readout=True,
readout_format='.1f',
```

For more information on different slider options, check out the documentation:

https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/7.6.2/examples/Widget%20List.html

Edit for further information:

widgets.IntSlider only works for integers (i.e., 1, 2, 3, ...), while widgets.FloatSlider works for floats (i.e., 1.1, 1.2, 2.4, 5.2, etc.). There are additional features such as widgets.FloatLogSlider for even smaller values (i.e., 1.001, 0.0002, etc.). I hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).